# Drawing text centered within a rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have code, similar to the following:

```
string myText = "This is a test";
Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10,100,100);
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.DrawString(myText, myFont, rect.X, rect.Y);
```

Although this works, what I would like to do is have the text vertically and horizontally centered within the dimensions of the rectangle. In addition, if its possible, I'd like to wrap the text if its too big to fit on one line. How do I do this in C#/GDI+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use one of the [`DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Overloads that takes a [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) <strike>You would have to check the Length of your Text using [`MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  to make sure it would fit and wrap it yourself.</strike> In looking further at the [`StringFormatFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it has a NoWrap Flag implying that the default is to wrap:

from last link:

> Text wrapping between lines when formatting within a rectangle is disabled. This flag is implied when a point is passed instead of a rectangle, or when the specified rectangle has a zero line length.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I just found out, wrapping will automatically occur, so this solution solves both my problems!

Comment: I tried all possible StringFormatFlags but could not find any that centers the text vertically in the rectangle as requested by the OP. Maybe an example of the code needed for this could be shared here ?

Answer (score 0):

the simple, un-researched way to do it:

to word-wrap break your strings up into smaller sub-strings.  I.e.

```
"this is"
"a test"
```

you can use the `String.Split()` method to split your strings up into words, and then append the words together until your string has reached a certain threshold.  and then make a new string.

As for centering, you can pad your individual strings with spaces.  for vertical centering, you can add some newlines to the beginning of your strings.

I'll leave the arithmetic involved to you.  it shouldn't be that hard.